# Best practice using angular architecture with components

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to wrap my mind arround angular components, to understand components better I'm developing a simple todo crud using the component architecture.

The problem is that I think it makes sense to put all operations of the crud in a single controller thus respecting the single responsibility principle but at the same time it is a good practice (I think) to split the views (one for list todos and delete another to create/update todos).

I know that multiple views with a single controller can be achieved using two separate components registering the same controller and some ng/ui-route magic, but using this blows up the encapsulation proposal that the components try to offer.

So, has anyone figured out a good solution to this problem?

Comment: take a look at angular2 todo, it will give you the idea https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/angular2-todo/

Comment: Can you write a basic code to see what is your issue? crud functions should be put in a service not in a controller.

Comment: @HadiAmiri thanks for the comment but the scope of the angular2 todo is simple, so all operations were implemented in a singe view (the todo has only one field).

Comment: @gyc thanks for the comment, I agree, all the crud operations has to be implemented and angular has the $resource which make it easy, the problem I described appears when it makes sense to split the component in multiple views but the controller must be the same to respect the single responsibility principle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to consider always the modularity, so you can use create a service to handle all the crud and API operations and it can be reused by your other controllers and directives.
Here is an example of how we did in our project. This is the git repo of on of my partners.

https://github.com/leog/epsilon

Comment: Thanks for the answer , I read the first part of your series , might be what I need I will read the rest and analyze the project.

Answer (score 1):

Here is demo from jhipster repository
[link](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/tree/master/src/main/webapp/app/entities/bank-account)

Using angular [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) in bank-account.state.js described all states with views and controllers.

Comment: thanks for the answer, that looks great! the only probleam I see is that the components cannot be export to another project that don't respect the view structure.